# AS3 Scrolling Background that switches direction on Button Hover

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, background, scroll

I have a scrolling background in flash that wraps. It currently scrolls to the left on enter frame. I have 2 arrows, left and right, that I would like to control the scrolling background with. The left arrow works right now but when I hover over the right arrow 2 things happen:
1: the background does not repeat
2: the movie clip jerks, thus causing a gap between the movie clips.

Any ideas?

```
            //Adds an event listener to the stage.
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftScroll); 

            //This function moves both the images to left. If the first and second 
            //images goes pass the left stage boundary then it gets moved to 
            //the other side of the stage. 
            function leftScroll(e:Event):void{
                pro1.x += scrollSpeed;  
                pro2.x += scrollSpeed;  

                if(pro1.x - scrollSpeed < -pro1.width){
                        pro1.x = pro1.width;
                        }else if(pro2.x - scrollSpeed < -pro2.width){
                        pro2.x = pro2.width;
                        }
            }
            L_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, FastLeft);
            L_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, SlowLeft);

            R_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, FastRight);
            L_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, SlowRight);


            function FastLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("left");
                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftScroll); 
                changeLeft();
            }

            function changeLeft()
            {
                scrollSpeed = gas;
                idle = false;

            }

            function SlowLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("left");
                if(idle == false){
                        scrollSpeed = neutral;
                }
            }


            function FastRight(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("left");
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftScroll);
                changeRight();
            }

            function changeRight()
            {
                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightScroll);
                scrollSpeed = gas;
                idle = false;

            }

            function rightScroll(e:Event):void{
                pro1.x -= scrollSpeed;  
                pro2.x -= scrollSpeed;
                if(pro1.x - scrollSpeed > -pro1.width){
                        pro1.x = pro1.width;
                        }else if(pro2.x - scrollSpeed > -pro2.width){
                        pro2.x = pro2.width;
                        }
            }

            function SlowRight(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("Right");
                if(idle == false){
                        scrollSpeed = neutral;
                }
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightScroll);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points I would make.

In general, I would avoid adding and removing so many event listeners at runtime.

By having so many separate enterFrame listeners, you're inviting disaster and confusion.

Here is my suggestion:

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
    L_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, FastLeft);
    L_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, SlowLeft);

    R_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, FastRight);
    R_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, SlowRight);

    scrollSpeed = 0;

    function onEnterFrame(e:Event)
    {
        pro1.x += scrollSpeed;  
        pro2.x += scrollSpeed;

        if (pro1.x < 0 - pro1.width)
        {
            pro1.x = stage.stageWidth;
        }
        else if (pro1.x >= stage.stageWidth)
        {
            pro1.x = 0 - pro1.width;
        }

        if (pro2.x < 0 - pro1.width)
        {
            pro2.x = stage.stageWidth;
        }
        else if (pro2.x >= stage.stageWidth)
        {
            pro2.x = 0 - pro2.width;
        }
    }


    function FastLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("left");
        scrollSpeed = -gas;
    }

    function SlowLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("left");
        scrollSpeed = -neutral;
    }


    function FastRight(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("left");
        scrollSpeed = gas;
    }

    function SlowRight(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("Right");
        scrollSpeed = neutral;
    }
```

This attempts to fix a few of your issues, and simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks Glitcher. worked like a charm. One error was thrown because of "onEnterFrame" but everything still worked.

Comment: That is an annoying warning caused by Flash thinking everyone is stupid ^_^ it can be safely ignored. If this helped please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer